# Adding attribute to NSMutableAttributedString on a specific range

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nsrange

I'm trying to add a background attribute to my `NSMutableAttributedString` for a specific range, which is working fine as long as the start range is 0. Whenever I try to pass a index to the function the background gets added to a lot more text than intended.

Here is a video demonstrating the issue. Whenever the user writes a wrong letter the issue appears.

[Video demonstration](https://youtu.be/kpHeEzpcIVI)

**Code:**

```
var index = 0

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    guard let char = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return true }
    let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
    if (isBackSpace == -92)
    {
        addBackground(color: .clear, from: index - 1, to: index)
        index -= 1
    }
    else
    {
        if charactersDoesMatch(char: string, i: index)
        {
            addBackground(color: .green, from: 0, to: index + 1)
        }
        else
        {
            //As you can see im trying to add it from the current index to the next one only.
            addBackground(color: .red, from: index, to: index + 1)
        }
        index += 1
    }
    return true
}

private func addBackground(color: UIColor, from: Int, to: Int)
{
    attributedText?.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor, value: color, range: NSMakeRange(from, to))
    toTypelabel.attributedText = attributedText
}
```

Comment: Can you add the value of index when it starts adding wrong attribute? or any screenshot of the debugger when the wrong attribute is added?

Comment: The first time the error happens in the video the index is 9. So the red color should only be applied to 9 until 10. I'll try to make a video of the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out your problem

```
func NSMakeRange(_ loc: Int, 
           _ len: Int) -> NSRange
```

Takes parameters location and second one is length, so when entering wrong value you enter 1 as parameter meaning only one character should be colored in red

```
addBackground(color: .red, from: index, to: 1)
```

For more read apple documentation: 
[NSMakeRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1417188-nsmakerange)

Comment: I should learn to read up on documentation better, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, I also forget sometimes to read documentation, but we should read it because it will save us a lot of time later :)

Comment: Worst thing is I did read it, I just assumed it was a "from - to" range 